# Getting a filename and save it in a variable in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to get the name of a file that gets created by some other process inside a folder. It's in a path where **only this file** exists. It's in this path:

```
/directory/which/only/contains/this/one/file/
```

The file's full filename could then be for example:

```
/directory/which/only/contains/this/one/file/xZqsdtae123456.txt
```

How can I get the name of this file (from the example above: `xZqsdtae123456.txt`) and then save it in a variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the generated file is the only one (as stated):

```
import os
yourfile = os.listdir("/home/user/Desktop/directory_which_only_contains_this_one_file")[0]
```

Comment: and how would one loop over the files under this directory assuming we dont have only one?